# unable to solve No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, tomcat, spring-boot, cors

I am using a spring boot and angular 2 project.
Every thing works fine if I test in local.
When I deploy .war in apache tomcat server, It shows this  famous errors :

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin .
```

I searched in the site of tomcat.
Adding this :

```
    <filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>10</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

does not change any thing.

Also, I tried this :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


    http.cors().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/*").permitAll();

    http.httpBasic();

    http.csrf().disable();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Spring boot app has to authorize http requests from the "micro-server" Angular2.

So you should authorize the http requests methods (GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS)  that you will need.
(headers : Access-Control-Request-Method).

You should authorize the possible(s) host of your angular2 server (http://localhost:8080 by example)
(headers : Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

And, you should authorize the headers present in the http request
(headers : Access-Control-Request-Headers)